# JSF Managed Bean not being called

Tags: jsf, jboss

I am getting started with JSF and trying out the following tutorial in Eclispe:
http://javing.blogspot.de/2013/01/how-to-create-new-jsf-21-project-and.html

I have got it working so that it compiles and deploys on JBoss EAP 6 without error. But I am not getting any output from my managed bean class, which consists of only one function which simply returns a text string. Here are the code files:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
version="3.0">  
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>  
  <context-param>  
       <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>  
       <param-value>Development</param-value>  
  </context-param>  
  <servlet>  
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>  
       <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>  
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>  
       <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
  <welcome-file-list>  
       <welcome-file>home.xhtml</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>  
 </web-app>
```

home.xhtml

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"  
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  
 <h:head>  
  <title>www.javing.blogspot.com</title>  
 </h:head>  
 <h:body>  
      <h:outputText value="#{hello.message}"/>  
 </h:body>  
 </html>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org
/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.zeeshan.www</groupId>
<artifactId>myJSFTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>JSF Test App</name>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6-jbossorg-2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>  
       <plugins>  
            <plugin>  
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
                 <version>2.3.2</version>  
                 <configuration>  
                      <source>1.6</source>  
                      <target>1.6</target>  
                      <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>  
                 </configuration>  
            </plugin>  
       </plugins>  
  </build>  
</project>
```

and the managed Bean class

package myJSFTest;

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean(name="hello")

public class Hello {

public String getMessage()
{   
    System.out.println("Hello world function called");
    return "www.javing.blogspot.com";  
}
}
```

I have verified via static output that it is indeed the managed bean class which is not returning any output.How to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, did you close your body tag? try follow this one for primefaces configuration and test http://www.primefaces.org/gettingStarted, and have you set the primefaces library?

Comment: Body tag closed and I have tried with primefaces as well, no output is being shown.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the `outputText`component inside a `h:form` tag:

```
<h:form>
   <h:outputText value="#{hello.message}"/> 
</h:form>
```

You can also choose to omit `outputText` all together and just place only `EL expression` in your page and it will work fine:

```
#{hello.message}
```

Comment: Page is not submitting the form data and so the `h:form` is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

`JSF 2.2` has new namespaces , it could be that your xhtml's are not rendering the components due to this. Could you correct the namepsace in xhtml as follows and give it a try,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
</html>
```